# Building .so files with Buildozer

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to build an APK with `.so` files. When I run `buildozer android debug deploy run logcat > logcat.txt`, my built app crashes on my phone and I get the following output:

```
E/linker  (18499): load_library(linker.cpp:757): library "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/sdk/qi/../libqimessaging.so" not found
E/linker  (18499): load_library(linker.cpp:757): library "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/sdk/qi/../libqipython.so" not found
E/linker  (18499): load_library(linker.cpp:757): library "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/sdk/qi/../libqipython.so" not found
I/python  (18499):  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  (18499):    File "/home/dan/kivytest/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 7, in <module>
I/python  (18499):    File "/home/dan/kivytest/.buildozer/android/app/sdk/naoqi.py", line 7, in <module>
I/python  (18499):    File "/home/dan/kivytest/.buildozer/android/app/sdk/qi/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
I/python  (18499):  ImportError: No module named _qi
```

In the file `sdk/qi/__init__.py` a bunch of `.so` files gets included. Because the includes fail, the later import fails and the app crashes.

I assume this is due to the `.so` files are not copied over properly into the `/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/sdk` folder. And I have no clue how to do that. This is what I tried so far:

```
android.add_src = /home/dan/kivytest/sdk
android.add_libs_armeabi = /home/dan/kivytest/sdk/*.so
android.library_references = /home/dan/kivytest/sdk
```

`add_libs_armeabi` causes the `.so` files to be copied to the `lib/armebi` folder in the APK. Other than that, I don't seem to be able to copy files to their right location. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty obvious. I totally missed the `source.include_exts` option. All one has to do is add file extension there.

Comment: Did that work for you? I am trying to do the same thing and nothing is getting copied. How exactly did you fix that?

Comment: No, in the end it did not work for reasons not related to this question. In my case the `.so` files weren't compiled for the ARM architecture.